# How to normalize columns in csv with hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I want to read a csv file and normalize the data. If I understand well how hadoop works, the mapper gets the data line by line.
I found this formula to normalize : Xnew = (X - Xmin)/(Xmax - Xmin)
So I need to know the minimum value of the column and the maximum in order to normalize.
How can I do that when in a mapper I have access to only one line at a time ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with finding the max and min value of a column it this type of application is the *scope* of the max/min variables where they can be accessed/modified in a parallel program where each instance is isolated from the other in terms of data. So what it needs to be done here is finding a way to have a *global scope* for the max/min variables in order to access and synchronize their own instances at the end of each map/reduce step.

The closest thing to this supported by Hadoop (at the time this answer was written) is the feature of **counters**, but they are designed in a way to only increment their values so you have to be creative to achieve your desired output.

The trick here is to actually have if-statements modifying the maximum and minimum counters to the column value of each line (in case they are the max and/or min), by

- **resetting the counter to zero by adding the negative value of itself** and then
- **increment the counter to the value of this specific line from the input `csv` file**

It's a bit tedious, but it does the job inside the `Map` function.

Now, for accessing the max and min values of the counters from the `Reduce` function, we can simply get them in a `setup` method before the execution of all reducer instances and use them for computing the new normalized values of each `key-value` pair.

So, let's say we have a `grades.csv` file stored in the `grades` directory in the `HDFS`, which the grades of the students at an elementary school class are stored like that:

```
Jack,3
Dennis,5
Kate,10
Nancy,9
Peter,1
Zack,2
Alex,4
Yvonne,10
Violet,1
Claire,2
```

We can find the max and min values at the `Map` stage while turning each line of the input file into `key-value` pairs, and compute the normalized grade for each student (using the max and min values of course) at the `Reduce` stage as seen below:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counters;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;


public class NormGrades
{
    public static enum Global_Counters 
    {
        MAX_GRADE,
        MIN_GRADE
    }

    /* input:  <byte_offset, line_of_tweet>
     * output: <student, grade>
     */
    public static class Map_Normalize extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> 
    {
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            String line = value.toString();
            String[] columns = line.split(",");

            int student_grade = Integer.parseInt(columns[1]);

            int max_grade = Math.toIntExact(context.getCounter(Global_Counters.MAX_GRADE).getValue());
            int min_grade = Math.toIntExact(context.getCounter(Global_Counters.MIN_GRADE).getValue());

            // in order to find the maximum grade, we first set the max grade counter to 0
            // by "increasing" it to the negative value of itself, and then increment by
            // the new found maximum grade
            if(student_grade > max_grade)
            {
                context.getCounter(Global_Counters.MAX_GRADE).increment(max_grade*(-1));  
                context.getCounter(Global_Counters.MAX_GRADE).increment(student_grade);
            }

            // in order to find the minimum grade, we first set the min grade counter to 0
            // by "increasing" it to the negative value of itself, and then increment by
            // the new found minimum grade
            // the contents on this if statement will be accessed at least once in order to
            // make sure that the min grade counter value is certainly higher than 0
            if((student_grade < min_grade) || (min_grade == 0))
            {
                context.getCounter(Global_Counters.MIN_GRADE).increment(min_grade*(-1));
                context.getCounter(Global_Counters.MIN_GRADE).increment(student_grade);
            }

            context.write(new Text(columns[0]), new IntWritable(student_grade));
        }
    }

    /* input:  <student, grade>
     * output: <student, normalized_grade>
     */
    public static class Reduce_Normalize extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, DoubleWritable> 
    {
        public int max_grade, min_grade;

        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            Cluster cluster = new Cluster(conf);
            Job current_job = cluster.getJob(context.getJobID());

            max_grade = Math.toIntExact(current_job.getCounters().findCounter(Global_Counters.MAX_GRADE).getValue());
            min_grade = Math.toIntExact(current_job.getCounters().findCounter(Global_Counters.MIN_GRADE).getValue());
        }

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            // each reducer instance is run for each student, so there is only one value/grade to access
            int student_grade = values.iterator().next().get();

            Double normalized_grade = (double) (student_grade - min_grade) / (max_grade - min_grade);

            context.write(key, new DoubleWritable(normalized_grade));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        Path input_dir = new Path("grades");
        Path output_dir = new Path("normalized_grades");

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        if(fs.exists(output_dir))
            fs.delete(output_dir, true);

        Job normalize_job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Normalize Grades");
        normalize_job.setJarByClass(NormGrades.class);
        normalize_job.setMapperClass(Map_Normalize.class);
        normalize_job.setReducerClass(Reduce_Normalize.class);   
        normalize_job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        normalize_job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        normalize_job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        normalize_job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);
        TextInputFormat.addInputPath(normalize_job, input_dir);
        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(normalize_job, output_dir);
        normalize_job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

The results are being stored as seen through the HDFS Browser in the following screenshot:
[image]